# Mongo --quiet Not Suppressing --eval output

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm writing this script that takes in t and uses it in test.js. I'm going to have the output be emailed to me and my collegues.

```
% mongo my_db --eval 't=9999;' --quiet test.js
9999
------------------------------------------------
Info about stuff going back 9999 days to 2012-08-17.
------------------------------------------------
Stuff x: 433321 (12.43%)
Stuff y: 2723426 (81.57%)
Total: 4524524524
```

Is there a way to not have what I pass in to --eval be outputted to console so I don't have that dangling '9999' at the top of my results?

**Edit: This may be a bug with the --quiet option**

See: 
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4391

Comment: +1 Thx for sharing the information that it may be a bug. I hate it when people discover solutions by themselves and don't share them :-).

Answer (score 3):

Bit of a hack, but until that bug gets fixed you could just pipe to `tail +2` first and that would exclude the output you do not want, something like:

```
% mongo my_db --eval 't=9999;' --quiet test.js | tail +2
```

This worked for me in a quick test to leave out the 9999 line.

Comment: Hmm - doesn't work for me. I keep getting tail: cannot open `+2' for reading: No such file or directory.

Comment: Ah, you need to add the -n flash after tail.

Comment: ah, must be a difference in the tail versions - I was running on a Mac FWIW

Comment: If this fixed it, it would be nice to get an accept or at least an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anybody stumbles over this issue. I had the same problem and got an answer on that solves the problem without shell magic:

[Use result from mongodb in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553535/use-result-from-mongodb-in-shell-script)

Answer (score -1):

I realize it has been a while. Posting a solution, hoping it might help someone who landed into this.

Prefixing a command with a void usually silences outputs.

For example, try:

```
$ mongo <server>/db script.js --eval 'void (yyyymm="2011-11")'
```

(NOTE: brackets are important)