# Use result from mongodb in shell script

Tags: bash, mongodb, shell

I am trying to use the result printed from a parameterized MongoDB script file in a bash script.

The call looks like this:

```
mongo --quiet server/db --eval "a='b'" mongoscript.js
```

Inside mongoscript.js there is a print statement that prints the value 'foo' I want to use in my shell script. The problem is that when I execute above statement I get:

```
b
foo
```

instead of just 'foo'

Thus, if I do

```
res=`mongo --quiet server/db --eval "a='b'" mongoscript.js`
```

res contains both lines.

I can of course solve this with

```
res=`mongo ... |tail -n 1`
```

but I am hoping there is a more general way to avoid this superfluous output.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The superfluous output is the result of your assignment of `a='b'`, which displays the result of the assignment in this context.

If you add the `var` keyword for variable assignment, you shouldn't have any extra output (and can still use the variable `a` in your script):

```
$ mongo --quiet --eval "var a='b'" mongoscript.js
foo
```

You can see the same behaviour in the `mongo` shell:

```
> a='b'
b
> var a='b'
>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, I suspected something as simple as this should exists.